# Company not found on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have been trying to search our business place (Bonteheuwel Library, Bluegum Street, Bonteheuwel, Cape Town, Western Cape) on Google Maps, but to no avail. Is there some way that Google can sort out this problem?

Answer (score 6):

You first need to add or claim your business to Google Maps. For this, follow the steps below:

> To add your business information to Google, you’ll need to create a local Google+ page (or get access to one, if it already exists).
>
> 1. Navigate to [Google My Business](https://business.google.com/).
>
>    - New to Google My Business? Don't worry--all you need is a Google account. It could be the same one you use for Gmail or Google+.
> 2. Search for your business using its name and address.
>
>    - Brands, organisations, or artists should follow [these steps](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4570248).
> 3. If you don’t see your business listed in the menu, click **No, these are not my businesses** or **I’ve correctly entered the business**. You’ll then be prompted to enter some details for your business. Make sure you enter an accurate, complete street address, and a phone number which reaches your business directly.
> 4. After you complete your business information, click **Submit**.

Then, you need to verify your business.

> The verification process helps ensure that your business information is accurate and that only you, the business owner or manager, has access to it. You may see one or several types of verification depending on the type of business you manage:
>
> #### Verify by postcard
>
> We'll send a postcard with a verification code to the business address you provided. Make sure your address complies with our [address entry guidelines](https://support.google.com/business/answer/2853879).
>
> If you're returning to verify after creating your page, visit [Google My Business](https://business.google.com/), choose the business you'd like to verify, and click **Verify now**.
>
> 1. On the postcard request screen, make sure that your address is displayed accurately. You can also add an **Optional contact name** to help your postcard reach you.
> 2. Click **Send postcard**.
> 3. Check the mail for your postcard—it should arrive in one to two weeks.
> 4. When you receive your postcard, enter your verification code [in your dashboard](https://business.google.com/).
>
> [Get help with missing or lost verification codes](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6161755).
>
> #### Verify by phone (available for select businesses)
>
> Phone verification isn't available for all businesses. If you don't see this option when you attempt to verify, request a postcard instead using the steps above.
>
> If you're returning to verify after creating your page, visit [Google My Business](https://business.google.com/), choose the business you'd like to verify, and click **Verify now**.
>
> 1. Make sure that you can directly answer your business phone number to receive your verification code.
> 2. Click **Verify by phone** to have the code sent to your phone via automated message.
>      Enter the code from the message [in your dashboard](https://business.google.com/).

[Source](https://support.google.com/business/answer/2911778?hl=en).